# How to filter groups by multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, filter, group-by

I am trying to drop all groups that does not meet a condition by using groupby.filter

My dataset consists of different location data merged into one, with salinity: merged_df[26] and temperature: merged_df[23]

```
group1 =merged_df.groupby("lonlat").filter(lambda x:  ((x[26] >= 34.0) | (x[23] <= -1.0)).any())
```

So, if the group contains rows in where the values meet the conditions I want to return a new data frame without those groups (dropping all rows of that group)

This line is not dropping the groups that does not meet the condition

The goal is to be able to make a plot like the one below, with only the values that met the conditions. If the temperature is below -1.0 OR if the salinity values are greater than 34 I want to be able to identify those groups and plot them. So the final plot should erase all locations (lonlat) with values above -1.0

[image]

Before doing this, I tried only filtering by the twoconditions without taking in account the location, but this will only remove the points that does not meet the condition and not the whole group (lonlat)
[image]

SOLUTION:Change condition from OR to AND

```
group1 =merged_df.groupby("lonlat").filter(lambda x:  ((x[26] >= 34.0) & (x[23] <= -1.0)).any())
```

[image]

Comment: `x[26] >= 34.0` Can you explain what this is intended to do in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to negate the *scalar bool* computed by [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) in each group.

```
group1 = (merged_df.groupby("lonlat").filter(
             lambda x: not ((x[26] >= 34.0) | (x[23] <= -1.0)).any())
         ) # add this --^
```

***Update :***

Based on the elements below, you need to use (`&`) instead of (`|`).

Comment: Thank you! But this is doing the opposite of what I want. I am aiming to keep the groups that meet that condition and filter out the ones that does not meet the condition.

Comment: Well, can you share a small example of your `merged_df` (a few rows/groups) *as text* ?

Comment: I think I figured it out! I needed to change my condition from OR to AND. I will post a pic of the final image